Question about a specific argument in the proof of Geometric Satake
Suppose $\tilde{G}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ is a flat affine group scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ (the p-adic integers) such that the fiber over the generic point $\tilde{G}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is  known to be of finite type over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and has finite dimension. Set $\kappa=\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ and let $G_{\kappa}=G_{\mathbb{F}_p}\times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)}\text{Spec}(\kappa)$ and let $(G_{\kappa})_{red}$ be the associated reduced scheme. Is it true that the reduced scheme $(G_{\kappa})_{red}$ is a finite type scheme over $\kappa$? I know that dim($G_{\kappa}$) is bounded above by dim($G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$).
This is a step in the proof of the Geometric Satake equivalence as in the Mirkovic-Vilonen paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401222.pdf), where  $\tilde{G}_{k}$ the group scheme constructed in section 11 so that the categoy of comodules of the associated Hopf algebra is equivalent to the category of equivariant (constructible) perverse sheaves with $k$ coefficients on the (complex) affine Grassmannian of some fixed complex reductive group $G$, and as such has to be shown is the split reductive group with the dual root datum to $G$. The fact that $(\tilde{G}_{\kappa})_{red}$ is of finite type over $\kappa=\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is required in the argument on pages 35-36 where we approximate the group scheme with some finite type quotients with some properties. There is an argument right below equation 12.11(c) which somehow seems to use just a dimension bound to argue this, but I don't quite understand it.
Any help will be appreciated!

It seems that this argument was not quite correct, and the authors gave an errata giving an alternate argument which can be found here: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematics/volume-188/issue-3/Erratum-for-Geometric-Langlands-duality-and-representations-of-algebraic-groups/10.4007/annals.2018.188.3.6.full
